# vue template can't be injected into the related tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I use webpack to build a simple vue project , here is the three files

### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vue Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: "<p> test <p>"
});
```

### and the webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.vue$/, use: 'vue-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']},
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

### and what show in the browser is

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Vue Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

the template doesn't replace the  tag, I don't know why. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Vuejs injects content into #app only on runtime, not on compile-time. Unless you're doing SSR indeed.

Inspect the DOM with devtools inspector because the source-code of the page won't change.

Comment: yeah, I know. When I open the html file with browser, the main.js doesn't work